# Dataflow job stuck on worker startup with container errors

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was running a very simple job and got the following error:

```
(8a5049d0d5f7569e): Workflow failed. Causes: (8a5049d0d5f750f5): The Dataflow appears to be stuck. You can get help with Cloud Dataflow at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support.
```

The job_id is 2018-01-15_07_42_27-12856142394489592925

The code I used to run this job is as follows:
(function ReconstructConversation() returns right after it enters the function body)

```
pipeline_args.extend([
 '--runner=DataflowRunner',
 '--project=<my-project>',
 '--staging_location=gs://<my-project>/staging',
 '--temp_location=gs://<my-project>/tmp',
 '--job_name=xxx',
 '--num_workers=30'
])


pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    filenames = (p | beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query='SELECT UNIQUE(page_id) as page_id FROM [%s]'%known_args.input_table, validate=True)) 
               | beam.ParDo(ReconstructConversation())
               | beam.io.Write(bigquery_io.BigQuerySink(known_args.output_table, schema=known_args.output_schema, validate=True)))
```

So far the code can successfully run the BigQuery input part, with logs showing BigQuery export finished successfully, but stuck after it starts the ParDo job.

Also here are the google cloud versions I used in the setup file.

```
'google-cloud == 0.27.0',
'google-cloud-storage == 1.3.2',
'google-apitools == 0.5.10'
```

The kubelet log in stackdriver seems to show there are some container errors:

```
[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container / 
Failed to check if disk space is available on the root partition: failed to get fs info for "root": unable to find data for container / 
Failed to check if disk space is available for the runtime: failed to get fs info for "runtime": unable to find data for container / 
Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: unable to find data for container /
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Yiqing

Comment: Provide more details

Comment: It's a three step workflow:basically reading data from bigquery, processing it using ParDo and writing it back.
The bigquery export job was finished successfully, but it seems like the ParDo job gets stuck right after it started:
This seems to be the main error in stackdriver:
getPodContainerStatuses for pod "dataflow-reconstruction-test-01131953-422a-harness-q133_default(5553b5c369dde909da7e117a5c218182)" failed: rpc error: code = 2 desc = Error: No such container: 1c2ce70ed4a8b65aecaeb2e90611007dcf86c2bc09dd672fb894c41536b2460f

Comment: Logs also show failed to find container.

Comment: The failure might be triggered by Autoscaling. "Startup of the worker pool in zone us-central1-f reached 6 workers, but the goal was 30 workers. The service will retry. QUOTA_EXCEEDED: Quota 'IN_USE_ADDRESSES' exceeded.  Limit: 100.0 in region us-central1".

Comment: I simplified the workflow and stopped all the other dataflow jobs in the project, then the autoscaling problem disappeared, but the stuck problem stayed.

Comment: I've updated the question, could you look at it again? Thank you!

Comment: I see that in the latest version of Beam, the version of `google-apitools` required is >= 0.5.18. Could you try setting that to at least 0.5.18? It seems that the setup of you worker is the one with problems, and specifically, the installation of the initial packages - so this might be it.

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I tried that but the problem still remains.

Comment: @yiqing_hua It seems like you are using the setup_file to create a custom package. Installation of custom packages could execute user defined code and could be stuck for any number of reasons. Seemingly this stage is taking a long time.  Can you check what options are you actually passing to your pipeline? We have found that you are pinning 2.1.0 version of Beam sdk in the setup.py file but using an environment with 2.0.0 version of the SDK. Could you try to fix the version mismatch and re-run?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few pieces of advice here:

- If your job is showing errors related to container setup, check your `setup.py`. If you don't see any evident issue, please file a support ticket with Cloud Dataflow support.
- Please don't use `BigQuerySink` directly. Instead, we recommend you use the `WriteToBigQuery` transform.

Comment: Hello, what do you refer by encouraging the usage of ReadFromBigQuery transform? There is no transform with such a name in the source code of apache beam.

Comment: ugh I'm so sorry : ( I guess I got confused.